# Postman and SparkJava response.body() aways null

Tags: java, postman, spark-java

My application was working fine before, but now my response.body() is always null and I don't know where the problem is.

this is my application main method(spark java framework)

```
    post("/customer", (request, response) -> {
        response.type("application/json");
        System.out.println(response.body());

        /*----*/
            return "final";
    });
```

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: Are you asking why the `request` body is empty or the `response` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, *you* have to define the response based on the `request`.

It's expected that the `response` doesn't contain a body at start of the method, you have to fill it.

Comment: I didn't quite understand, could you explain it to me in more detail? but anyway, it worked perfectly before I turned off the computer, and now it just doesn't work, it's like postman didn't even send a body on the request.

Comment: See my other comment, are you complaining about request or response body that is empty. Your question is not clear.